# Missing .js/.css files using OneUI V2.1 on 8.5.3 UP1

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

In the Domino server log I am receiving this error message:

HTTP Web Server: Couldn't find design note - xpDocLinks.js [the database path and name]

HTTP Web Server: Couldn't find design note - oneuiv2_1.css [the database path and name]

So these elements are needed in the database, but I can't figure out where to find them. This is on a fresh 8.5.3 UP1 install. I am using the Extension Library Application Layout and the other standard controls.

Any tips?

Thanks, 
Kendra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those elements are not part of the extension library/UP1. They are part of the enhanced XPages Teamroom template.

So these elements are referenced in the database that you are accessing - and are either not available in the database or not accessible due to substitution rules for instance.

I suggest that you search the db (using CTRL+H) for the names of the design elements to see where they are referenced.